# Question about infinite metric spaces and open sets

Tags: metric-spaces, advice

To prove :Let M  be an infinite metric space. Prove M contains an open set U s.t  U and $U^c $ are infinite

I am thinking to use contrapositive technique (~q-> ~p)

The Contrapositive Version

If U and $U^c $ are not open and finite show M is a finite metric space
( Can’t assume closed sets. I am on section 4.2)
I am using set theory and metric spaces by Kaplansky 
I can use everything up to 4.2

But if I decide the direct technique how do I argue with infinite subsets and metric spaces ?

I know that  the union of open sets is opened
Ref: 
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2118888/748810

So by the Ref U is opened and infinite.( A wild guess. I hope I don’t 
  choke)

Comment: I have been looking for a def. of an infinite metric space. Have not found one. I can’t make it any clearer. This is actual wording out of the book other that s.t which means such that

Comment: An infinite metric space is just an infinite set $X$ with a metric $d:X\times X\to [0,\infty)$ with, as usual, the topology being generated by the base (basis) of all open $d$-balls. (That is, any $Y\subseteq X$ us open iff $Y$ is the union of a family of open $d$-balls.)

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Consider two cases:

(I) The metric space is discrete. Then the claim is evident.

(II) The metric space is not discrete. Find an injective sequence that converges and consider the set of its terms with odd index together with its limit. Show that this set is closed (for example, show it is compact) and let $U$ be the complement of this set.

Comment: I can’t assume convergence. I have open balls the union of open

Comment: I don't say you have to assume it. I say you have to prove such thing exists.

Comment: For (2) Theorem 30 a subSet of metric space is open iff it is express Ible as a union of open balls. Using your suggestion, the proof of convergence sequence more or less is given in section 4.3

Comment: Thanks. I apparently walked into a hornets nest with this problem.
https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/infinite-metric-space.178662/